# How can i extract data from a chart selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to know how can I extract data from a chart using selenium python. I want to extract data from [this web](https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/rent/apartment-for-rent-dubai-dubai-marina-marina-gate-marina-gate-1-6951117.html). I'm using python. I want to extract all the point that are in the chart. Thanks.

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/svg/g[12]").text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is not needed, as there is an api endpoint for the graph. I used the requests module for this. This will print all the points on the graph and also points not on the graph (such as dates from 2016/17). This api endpoint can also be used for more information if you look at it.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/api/property/6951117/market-trends')

trends = r.json()
print(trends['data']['attributes']['graph']['chart_data'])
```

This will return:

```py
[{'date': 'Feb, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 160000}, {'date': 'Mar, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 155000}, {'date': 'Apr, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'May, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Jun, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Jul, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 145000}, {'date': 'Aug, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 149999}, {'date': 'Sep, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Oct, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Nov, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 145000}, {'date': 'Dec, 2016', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 145000}, {'date': 'Jan, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Feb, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 150000}, {'date': 'Mar, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 145000}, {'date': 'Apr, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 145000}, {'date': 'May, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 140000}, {'date': 'Jun, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 140000}, {'date': 'Jul, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 140000}, {'date': 'Aug, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 139000}, {'date': 'Sep, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Oct, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Nov, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Dec, 2017', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Jan, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Feb, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Mar, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Apr, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'May, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Jun, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 135000}, {'date': 'Jul, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 130000}, {'date': 'Aug, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 125000}, {'date': 'Sep, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 125000}, {'date': 'Oct, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 120000}, {'date': 'Nov, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 120000}, {'date': 'Dec, 2018', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 120000}, {'date': 'Jan, 2019', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 120000}, {'date': 'Feb, 2019', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 120000}, {'date': 'Mar, 2019', 'label': 'Dubai Marina', 'value': 110000}]
```

Comment: How to know if there is an API for a website?

Comment: Well, this one seems to be their private api (undocumented). If you go to the website, go to the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools, filter by XHR and reload the page, then you will find a market-trends request.

Comment: but i really want to know how make it with selenium . Because all my code is in selenium. and i dont know to extract the '6951117' from the url... to put in the request them...